# Error running npm run dev in github action workflows

Tags: php, laravel, npm, github-actions, npm-run

So I am trying to connect a github repository to cpanel. I set-up the secrets, the .github/workflows/main.yml file and then ran it. When I look at my github-action, it is not working. The following are the errors that I am getting. I really have no idea why. Please help.

```
Run npm run dev

> dev
> vite


  VITE v3.0.2  ready in 397 ms

  ➜  Local:   http://127.0.0.1:5173/
  ➜  Network: use --host to expose

  LARAVEL v9.42.2  plugin v0.5.0

/home/runner/work/github-actions-attendancedashboard/github-actions-attendancedashboard/node_modules/laravel-vite-plugin/dist/index.js:108
                        server.config.logger.info(`  ${picocolors_1.default.green('➜')}  ${picocolors_1.default.bold('APP_URL')}: ${picocolors_1.default.cyan(appUrl.replace(/:(\d+)/, (_, port) => `:${picocolors_1.default.bold(port)}`))}`);
                                                                                                                                                                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/runner/work/github-actions-attendancedashboard/github-actions-attendancedashboard/node_modules/laravel-vite-plugin/dist/index.js:108:166)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

my main.yaml file

```
on: 
  push:
    branches:
      - main
name:  Deploy website on push
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup PHP
      uses: shivammathur/setup-php@v2
      with:
        php-version: 8.1.11

    - name: Cache Composer packages
      id: composer-cache
      uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: vendor
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-php-${{ hashFiles('**/composer.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-php-

    - name: Save state
      run: echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_STATE

    - name: Set output
      run: echo "{name}={value}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: composer install --prefer-dist --no-progress
        
    - name: Update dependencies
      run: composer update

    - name: install npm 
      run:  npm install

    - name: run npm 
      run:  npm run dev       
    
    - name:  Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.3
      with:
        server: ftp.sabahloka.com
        username: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
        password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
        server-dir: /home/sabahlok/hackathon2.dfa-learning.sabahloka.com/
```

my package.json

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.2",
        "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
        "alpinejs": "^3.0.6",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.7",
        "axios": "^0.25",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.5.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.4.14",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.1.0",
        "vite": "^3.0.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "chart.js": "^3.8.0",
        "chartjs-adapter-moment": "^1.0.0",
        "flatpickr": "^4.6.13",
        "moment": "^2.29.4"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume if you are pushing this to a server, then this is a production or staging server. In which case, you'd likely want to build your assets, rather than run the hot reload server that vite uses.

```
- name: install npm 
  run:  npm ci

- name: run npm 
  run:  npm run build
```

`npm ci` is generally the command to use in pipelines: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-ci - the reasons for that are in this documentation.

`npm run build` will tell vite to build the assets for production, so it will bundle them together, rather than using a hotreload server to serve the assets. This should then mean you'll have a built public directory to upload, rather than a hotreload server serving the files.